# text shadow on off with a fade

Tags: jquery, css

I have some text, and some text shadow applied to it. I want that to behave like "on/off".

css:

```
a.playnowanchor.glow {
  text-shadow: 1px 0px 20px #fff;
}
```

html:

```
<a href="#" class="playnowanchor">PLAY NOW</a>
```

I have achieved the effect with jquery:

```
setInterval(function() {
        $('a.playnowanchor').toggleClass('glow');
    }, 400);
```

and it basically works fine, but I would like a transition to happen as well.

Can this be done with somehow with just css, because I do not know a way to do this with jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS animation to achieve this.

For repetition include infinite in animation like the example:

```css
body {background:salmon} /* for testing purpose */

a.playnowanchor {
    -webkit-animation: animate .6s infinite;
    -moz-animation: animate .6s infinite;
    animation: animate .6s infinite;
} 

/* Keyframes */
@-webkit-keyframes animate{
    0% {text-shadow: none;}
    50% {text-shadow: 1px 0px 20px #fff;}
    100% {text-shadow: none;}
}
@-moz-keyframes animate{
    0% {text-shadow: none;}
    50% {text-shadow: 1px 0px 20px #fff;}
    100% {text-shadow: none;}
}
@keyframes animate{
    0% {text-shadow: none;}
    50% {text-shadow: 1px 0px 20px #fff;}
    100% {text-shadow: none;}
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="playnowanchor">PLAY NOW</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

Only use css transition to make it.

Hope to help you.

**EDIT**

If you want to animate it automatically, you can try `keyframe`.

```
.hi {
    -webkit-animation: text-animate 5s infinite;
    animation: text-animate 5s infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes text-animate {
    0%   {text-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;}
    100%  {text-shadow:0}
}
@keyframes text-animate {
    0%   {text-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;}
    100%  {text-shadow: 0}
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5uscwf72/3/)

Comment: but I do not need it on hover but to go on/off on its own.